# Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my use of 
google.cloud.firestore

I have a "blinking" error:

```
RetryError: RetryError(Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient, caused by <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.INTERNAL, GOAWAY received)>)
```

Sentry error stack ended in call of:

```
@transactional
def _create_chat_with_apply_tx(tx, c, ordered_uids, message, has_interview, for_shadow, source):
```

With no data of what was called inside .

Comment: Hard to tell with so little information. Network error?